# Use CSS hover with external SVG files?

Tags: css, svg, hover, css-animations

I have an external SVG file with an inline stylesheet like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300.00006 244.18703" height="244.19" width="300" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    svg, svg * {
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    svg g {
      transition: fill 0.2s;
      fill: #303030;
    }
    svg:hover g {
      fill: #6CADDE;
    }
  ]]></style>
  </defs>
  <g style="" transform="translate(-539.18 -568.86)">
    <path d="m633.9 812.04c112.46 0 (...) 27.464"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

When I open this file by itself in Firefox, it works just as intended. However, if I use an  element in an HTML file as `<img src="image.svg">` and link it to the SVG, then the hover animation does not trigger. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show us full code including the SVG

Comment: @TemaniAfif updated

Comment: it's working fine for me on Chrome .. i have the hover effect

Comment: can create a complete fiddle where your reproduce the behavior ?

Comment: When SVG is used as an image i.e. via an <img> file or as a background image it is not interactive so things like :hover won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working you need to insert the SVG in HTML code itself.

Adding an external SVG using src will only allow adding CSS to the overall SVG element and not the interior subtags.

also, can you show some more code? So that it will be better to understand the problem well.

eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SVG</title>
  <style media="screen">
    circle:hover{
      fill: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with my full code, the CSS is inside the SVG file itself. Does this change things at all?

Comment: Yes, I got your point. You need to copy the complete SVG code from image.svg and paste it in your HTML file instead of linking it with src. The problem is when you load the HTML page. your Inline style for image.svg is not used instead the one on your HTML file is being used.

So first copy the complete SVG code from image.svg paste it into your HTML file and then apply CSS to <g> tag.